# Adding class to next 5 divs with specific name

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to add class to specific number (5) of elements? I want to make a news page where when one clicks, 5 more articles show up. Action must be repeated.

```
const loadMorePostsBtn = document.getElementById('loadMoreBtn');
const allPostsCheck = document.querySelectorAll('.top-news');

function moreview(){
  allPostsCheck.forEach(singlepost => {
    singlepost.classList.remove('hidden');
    hiddenPostsPopup.textContent = $('#allNews > .hidden').length;
    }
  });
}
```

If it helps, this is code which is working but doesn't have a specific number

Comment: Just a hint - you can see how many posts you have visible / hidden using the `lenght` property on the `querySelectorAll` return. This way, you can have lets say 100 total posts of which 40 are not hidden. So then you can remove the `hidden` class from the next 5 elements (40 + 5).

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/slice/ can help you to easily cut out part of an element selection.

Comment: It's certainly possible, but we need more information than you've shown. What's your "*[mcve]* code"? We need that to reproduce the problem (please note we need *minimal* and *representative* requirements code, we don't need the full code of your app - that's too much to dig through - and it doesn't need to be data from the app, just something that's similar enough).

Comment: @DimitarVeljanovski Probably best to use the `length` property though ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have used `for` loop instead of `foreach`,

because `foreach` runs for all elements but in `for` you can specify for example run 5 times not more

Here's a simple example:

```js
function more() {
  const amount = 5;
  const hiddenPosts = document.querySelectorAll(".top-news.hidden");
  const remaining = hiddenPosts.length;

  if (remaining > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < (remaining >= amount ? amount : remaining); i++) {
      hiddenPosts[i].classList.remove("hidden");

    }
  } else {
    alert('no more posts')
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
}

.top-news {
  padding: 15px 25%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.top-news.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-news">1</div>
<div class="top-news">2</div>
<div class="top-news">3</div>
<div class="top-news">4</div>
<div class="top-news">5</div>
<div class="top-news hidden">6</div>
<div class="top-news hidden">7</div>
<div class="top-news hidden">8</div>
<div class="top-news hidden">9</div>
<div class="top-news hidden">10</div>
<div class="top-news hidden">11</div>
<button onclick="more()">Load More</button>
```

Another example with a simple fade animation:

```js
function more() {
  const amount = 5;
  const hiddenPosts = document.querySelectorAll(".top-news.hidden");
  const remaining = hiddenPosts.length;

  if (remaining > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < (remaining >= amount ? amount : remaining); i++) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        hiddenPosts[i].classList.remove("hidden");
      }, 300 * i);
    }
  } else {
    alert('no more posts')
  }
}
```

```css
@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
}

.top-news {
  padding: 15px 25%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  margin: 5px 0;
  animation: fadeIn 1s ease;
}

.top-news.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-news">1</div>
<div class="top-news">2</div>
<div class="top-news">3</div>
<div class="top-news">4</div>
<div class="top-news">5</div>
<div class="top-news hidden">6</div>
<div class="top-news hidden">7</div>
<div class="top-news hidden">8</div>
<div class="top-news hidden">9</div>
<div class="top-news hidden">10</div>
<div class="top-news hidden">11</div>
<button onclick="more()">Load More</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a class on nth child where n is the 5th child of the parent element - https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: Giving a link to w3schools is of questionable utility when there are much better sources (like, say, [the document which defines the pseudo-class](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#nth-child-pseudo)). Also, it is always better to show an example of how to use a technique than to just say "use this technique".